# Cannot start JUnit tests using Appium in Eclipse

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, junit, appium

I want to start JUnit tests using Eclipse, with appium. When I right click and select run as, at project I select my project, but at test nothing is displayed. Any ideas where did I go wrong?

My class build is the following:

```
public WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  // set up appium
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.1");
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
  capabilities.setCapability("app", "the path to the simulator app is correct, tested it with other software");
  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@Test
public void test01() throws InterruptedException {

  Thread.sleep(5000);

}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your following libraries:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```

Also, try to change @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod to @BeforeTest/@AfterTest

Comment: I have it imported, and still no luck with it. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: try to run it as testng

Comment: Nope, it does not work. I attempted to run as testng, still nothing... also changed the @BeforeMethod, still no result.

Comment: look at tmy updated answer.. i just tested on my PC and it works fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you, you helped a lot... I had some imports which collided with the junit imports, and could not start the tests. It took more than it should for me to observe that.